# How to configure encryption for the Oracle Database Connection Pool in Apache Tomcat 8

Tags: oracle, tomcat, encryption, connection

I have an Apache Tomcat 8 with configured Oracle Database Connection Pool (using context.xml file). 
Also I have a web app running on this server. 
Now I need to add an encryption for connections I take from Oracle Database Connection Pool.

How to add Properties to Oracle Database Connection Pool configuration in Tomcat?

My context.xml file:

```
<Context>
  <Resource maxWait="-1" 
            maxIdle="10" 
            maxActive="20" 
            password="password " 
            username="username" 
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =
                 (ADDRESS_LIST =
                 (ADDRESS = 
                 (PROTOCOL = TCP)
                 (HOST = host.ttt.intranet)
                 (PORT = 2000))
                 )
                 (CONNECT_DATA =
                 (SERVICE_NAME = TEST)
                 )
                 )" 
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"         
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            auth="Container" 
            name="jdbc/Ora"/>
</Context>
```

For standalone applications I just add properties as parameters for method 
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(String url, Properties info)

```
Properties info= new Properties();
info.setProperty(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL, oracle.net.ano.AnoServices.ANO_REQUIRED);
info.setProperty(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_TYPES, "( "+ oracle.net.ano.AnoServices.ENCRYPTION_AES256 + ","+ oracle.net.ano.AnoServices.ENCRYPTION_AES192 + ","+  oracle.net.ano.AnoServices.ENCRYPTION_AES128 + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to add the connectionProperties attribute.   For example:

```
<Context>
  <Resource maxWait="-1" 
            maxIdle="10" 
            maxActive="20" 
            password="password " 
            username="username" 
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =
                 (ADDRESS_LIST =
                 (ADDRESS = 
                 (PROTOCOL = TCP)
                 (HOST = host.ttt.intranet)
                 (PORT = 2000))
                 )
                 (CONNECT_DATA =
                 (SERVICE_NAME = TEST)
                 )
                 )" 
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"         
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            auth="Container" 
            name="jdbc/Ora"
            connectionProperties="oracle.net.encryption_client=REQUESTED"/>
</Context>

See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/dbcp/dbcp2/BasicDataSource.html#setConnectionProperties-java.lang.String-
```

for details on how to set connectionProperties